# Using Camera LED Flash with OpenCV on Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, camera, computer-vision

I have an application using OpenCV for Android and was wondering if it was possible to enable the camera's LED.

Currently my camera is set up using the following code:
`camera = new VideoCapture(Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID);`

All examples I've seen which enable the LED Flash require `Camera.Parameters` which I don't have access to with this camera setup.

Is there any simple way to enable the LED without switching to using the basic `Camera` class for my videostream, as this tends to be much slower.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenCV for Android 2.4, you can do this,

```
mCamera.set(
  Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE,
  Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_ON
);
```

Other options are: `CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_AUTO`, `CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_OFF`, `CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_TORCH` and`CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_REDEYE`.

However, using this causes the application to automatically close on my tablet (Asus TF101). Hopefully it works on others.

Comment: Cheers, I was using OpenCV for Android 2.3 but will try this with 2.4.

Answer (score 4):

You can use extends JavaCameraView

public class Tutorial2View extends JavaCameraView{

```
private static final String TAG = "Sample::Tutorial2View";

private Context myreference;
private static boolean isFlashLightON = false;
public Tutorial2View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.myreference = context;
}

public List<String> getEffectList() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();
}

public boolean isEffectSupported() {
    return (mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect() != null);
}

public String getEffect() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getColorEffect();
}

public void setEffect(String effect) {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setColorEffect(effect);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
}

public void setResolution(Size resolution) {
    disconnectCamera();
    mMaxHeight = resolution.height;
    mMaxWidth = resolution.width;
    connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
}

public Size getResolution() {
    return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
}

// Setup the camera
public void setupCameraFlashLight() {
    Camera  camera = mCamera;
    if (camera != null) {
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

        if (params != null) {
            if (isFlashLightON) {
                isFlashLightON = false;
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();
            } else {
                isFlashLightON = true;
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();

            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Call setupCameraFlashLight(); to ON OFF the LED light

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no easy way to do this. The only option is to use the default Android Camera class and take the slight performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

If you use JavaCameraView you can simply add on the end two methods to your JavaCameraView.java class:

```
public void turnOffTheFlash() {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(params.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}

public void turnOnTheFlash() {
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(params.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
}
```

You can run them in your activity as follow:

```
private JavaCameraView javaCameraView;

javaCameraView.turnOnTheFlash();

javaCameraView.turnOffTheFlash();
```

Mayby you should use FLASH_MODE_ON rather than FLASH_MODE_TORCH.

It works for my on OpenCV 2.4.9.